# How to get 2 different aggregates of previous 12 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, analytics

Using sql server 2008

I'm looking for a single sql solution.

Right now I have two queries and cannot figure out how to get it into a single sql resultset.

I don't want to use temp tables if at all possible.

I want to count all opened and closed calls for each week over the last 12 weeks given an end date.
Any call status > 3 signifies a closed call.

```
-- Create table with data
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--drop table calltable
--go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[calltable](
    [PKID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [incident_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [call_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [status] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (145, CAST(0x0000A36500F55347 AS DateTime), 9)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (192, CAST(0x0000A3A200F5534C AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (105, CAST(0x0000A36800F5534C AS DateTime), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (732, CAST(0x0000A39C00F5534C AS DateTime), 9)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (62, CAST(0x0000A35B00F5534C AS DateTime), 9)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (188, CAST(0x0000A394010A48D0 AS DateTime), 7)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (844, CAST(0x0000A380010A48F1 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (77, CAST(0x0000A387010A48F1 AS DateTime), 8)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES (263, CAST(0x0000A352010A48F1 AS DateTime), 8)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 556, CAST(0x0000A394010A48F1 AS DateTime), 8)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 546, CAST(0x0000A37E010A5D8F AS DateTime), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 17, CAST(0x0000A378010A5D8F AS DateTime), 5)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 652, CAST(0x0000A377010A5D94 AS DateTime), 7)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 107, CAST(0x0000A356010A5D94 AS DateTime), 9)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 96, CAST(0x0000A3A5010A5D94 AS DateTime), 7)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 668, CAST(0x0000A36D010A5E33 AS DateTime), 6)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 756, CAST(0x0000A37A010A5E33 AS DateTime), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 286, CAST(0x0000A361010A5E33 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 591, CAST(0x0000A39D010A5E33 AS DateTime), 7)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 975, CAST(0x0000A37F010A5E33 AS DateTime), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 788, CAST(0x0000A37C010A5F0B AS DateTime), 9)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 892, CAST(0x0000A390010A5F10 AS DateTime), 9)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 51, CAST(0x0000A38C010A5F14 AS DateTime), 10)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 302, CAST(0x0000A356010A5F14 AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[calltable] ([incident_number], [call_date], [status]) VALUES ( 717, CAST(0x0000A374010A5F14 AS DateTime), 6)



-- Queries
DECLARE @WeeksBack SMALLINT
DECLARE @ReportEndDate DATETIME

SET @ReportEndDate = '2014-09-27'
SET @WeeksBack = 12

SELECT ct.call_date
   , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + (CAST(DATEPART(YY, ct.call_date) AS CHAR(4)))) + ((DATEPART(WK, ct.call_date)) - 1), 6) AS reportstartdate
   , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + (CAST(DATEPART(YY, ct.call_date) AS CHAR(4)))) + ((DATEPART(WK, ct.call_date)) - 1), 5) AS reportenddate
   , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(week, ct.call_date)) AS OpenedCallCt
   , NULL
FROM calltable ct
WHERE ct.call_date <= @ReportEndDate
   AND ct.call_date >= dateadd(day, (- 7 * @WeeksBack), @ReportEndDate)

SELECT ct.call_date
   , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + (CAST(DATEPART(YY, ct.call_date) AS CHAR(4)))) + ((DATEPART(WK, ct.call_date)) - 1), 6) AS reportstartdate
   , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + (CAST(DATEPART(YY, ct.call_date) AS CHAR(4)))) + ((DATEPART(WK, ct.call_date)) - 1), 5) AS reportenddate
   , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(week, ct.call_date)) AS ClosedCallCt
   , NULL
FROM calltable ct
WHERE ct.call_date <= @ReportEndDate
   AND ct.call_date >= dateadd(day, (- 7 * @WeeksBack), @ReportEndDate)
   and ct.STATUS > 3
```

Query1 Resultset (partial):

```
 reportstartdate           reportenddate             OpenedCallCt
------------------------- ------------------------- --------------
 2014-07-06 00:00:00.000   2014-07-12 00:00:00.000    2
 2014-07-06 00:00:00.000   2014-07-12 00:00:00.000    2
 2014-07-13 00:00:00.000   2014-07-19 00:00:00.000    2
 2014-07-13 00:00:00.000   2014-07-19 00:00:00.000    2
 2014-07-20 00:00:00.000   2014-07-26 00:00:00.000    1
```

Query2 Resultset (partial):

```
reportstartdate reportenddate   ClosedCallCt
2014-07-06 00:00:00.000 2014-07-12 00:00:00.000 1
2014-07-13 00:00:00.000 2014-07-19 00:00:00.000 1
2014-07-20 00:00:00.000 2014-07-26 00:00:00.000 1
```

How can I obtain the following resultset with just a query and no intermediate table use??

Desired Resultset (partial) :

```
reportstartdate reportenddate   OpenedCallCt    ClosedCallCt
2014-07-06 00:00:00.000 2014-07-12 00:00:00.000 2   1
2014-07-13 00:00:00.000 2014-07-19 00:00:00.000 2   1
2014-07-20 00:00:00.000 2014-07-26 00:00:00.000 1   1
```

Thanks for any help and let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ct.call_date
   , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + (CAST(DATEPART(YY, ct.call_date) AS CHAR(4)))) + ((DATEPART(WK, ct.call_date)) - 1), 6) AS reportstartdate
   , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + (CAST(DATEPART(YY, ct.call_date) AS CHAR(4)))) + ((DATEPART(WK, ct.call_date)) - 1), 5) AS reportenddate
   , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(week, ct.call_date)) AS OpenedCallCt
   , count(case when ct.status > 3 then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(week, ct.call_date)) AS ClosedCallCt   
FROM calltable ct
WHERE ct.call_date <= @ReportEndDate
   AND ct.call_date >= dateadd(day, (- 7 * @WeeksBack), @ReportEndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed, based on the original example, will work fine provided that this is a one off report.  If you want the report to work regardless of the @ReportEndDate or @WeeksBack, then you may want to consider this solution:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab18a4/9/0